# Conditional EventListener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, dom-events

I was just wondering if there is a way to define conditional event listener i.e. is there a way to listen for the event only if some condition is met.

I think I am asking for an unorthodox stuff, or there is a way already exists which I am oblivious of.

Example:

Let `'lastRepeat'` be an event emitted by the directive when ng-repeat ends.

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.$on('lastRepeat', callback);  // Here the callback will be called every time lastRepeat event is emitted by the directive 
});
```

But what I am looking for is something like this (This is what I have thought of, solution need not use same approach):

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  function foo(){
    if(bool)
      $scope.$on('lastRepeat', callback); // Problem listening like this is that a listener is created everytime foo is called and condition is met and hence we end up having multiple listeners
  }
)};
```

Basically I want to avoid this multiple creation of listeners. Is there a way I can store this listener like a variable and listen only if some condition is met.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are looking for. Is it the adding of the listener that you want to be conditional, or the actual reacting to the event?

Comment: Actual reacting of the event to be conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  var condition = false;
  var callback = function () {};

  $scope.$on('lastRepeat', function() {
    if (!condition) return;
    callback();    
  });
});
```

Comment: Currently, I am using the exact workaround, but In my case I have multiple conditions and I need to do different stuff on each condition for which I have simply extended the above answer. But one problem would be bookkeeping of which condition is happening and may lead to problem as the code scales. That is why I want to listen at function scope instead of listening at controller's scope.

Comment: Don't think you can listen at function scope in the way you want to, unless I'm misunderstanding. But you could create a service that manages pairs of conditions and actions.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.What you are suggesting is to listen inside a service function instead of controller and then call that service function inside controller's function.

Comment: For example, a service that has a function that accepts a condition and an action (you could pass more data, for example if you don't want the event `lastRepeat` to be hard coded in the service). The service could use the rootscope to listen, and when the event happens it will iterate all condtions and take the action if condition was met. Hard to give a good answer though without knowing the full use case.

Comment: Note that if you use `$rootScope` in the service there must be some way for the controller or subscriber to unscribe. A controller would unsubscribe in `$scope.$on('$destroy'` for example.